# Facebook - Requires either publish_actions permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

For my personal account on Facebook, I asked for the following permissions as scopes: publish_actions, manage_pages, publish_pages.

When I publish from the site I develop a lambda publication:

**POST** https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/me/feed

```
{
    "message": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
    "link": "https://www.google.fr/"
}
```

I receive this error:

> Requires either publish_actions permission, or manage_pages and
>   publish_pages as an admin with sufficient administrative permission

However, it seems to me that it is possible not to submit requests for permissions when it comes to the administrator account that has the Facebook application.

Comment: publish_actions is deprecated, so you can only post as a page (page access token) or use the share dialog.

Comment: OK, thanks. Do you know how become Facebook API Partner to have this permission? I know it's possible but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: With the Graph API 3.0 release this permission disappeared from the Graph API Explorer and the permission documentation. So I don't think this is available. Don't know how to become a partner. I would be interested, too ;)

Comment: I think if you aren’t a “big player”, you can pretty much forget about that. If they still _wanted_ every average “Tom, Dick and Harry” to have access to this, then they could have left it as it was, by simply requiring app review to be able to use this. But they didn’t ...

Comment: @CBroe so you can confirm that this permission still exists? Would be interesting for my open source library ...

Comment: I just saw that it's only for big accounts ... They give over $ 10K a month ...

Comment: @Norbert no, I was just referring to any chances of becoming a “partner” that would still be allowed to post via API. For 3rd-party apps without a special partnership with Facebook, those permissions are gone.

Comment: How come scripts like [King poster](https://codecanyon.net/item/king-poster-facebook-multi-group-page-auto-post-php-script/13302046) are still able to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Graph API 3.0 release this permission disappeared from the Graph API Explorer and the permission documentation.